# Null pointer exception on bitmap while scrolling

Tags: android, facebook, bitmap, nullpointerexception

I am creating a bitmap which hold Facebook image cropped in a circular shape the code was working fine but wen there is a lot of images in the same activity its giving a null pointer exception while scrolling here is my code

```
//enter code here
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(obj.picture, Base64.DEFAULT);
                            Bitmap decodedByte =  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                     on this line i am getting a null pointer exception
                            Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(decodedByte.getWidth(), decodedByte.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                            BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(decodedByte, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
                            Paint paint = new Paint();
                            paint.setShader(shader);
                            Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
                            c.drawCircle(decodedByte.getWidth() / 2, decodedByte.getHeight() / 2, decodedByte.getWidth() / 2, paint);
                            holder.civilianImage.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);
```

i can see the image presented but while i scroll this error is shown.
Any help would be appreciated.
And one more thing i getting the image from Facebook but each image is different from the other one in resolution and while cropping the image is losing a lot of it how can i manage this also.

```
enter code here
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsFeed>
{
    public static final int missionLayout = 0;
    public static final int badgeLayout = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = badgeLayout + 1;
    private NewsFeed obj;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public ListViewAdapter ()
    {
        super(CityNewsFeedActivity.this,R.layout.activity_activity_city_news_feed,newsfeed);
        mInflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount()

    {
        return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
         obj = newsfeed.get(position);
        return obj.category.equals("mission")? missionLayout : badgeLayout;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder=null;

        if (convertView == null)
        {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
   if (obj.accepted_rejected.equals("success"))
                        {
                            holder.relativeLayoutMission.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mission_successful);
                            Float alpha = Float.valueOf("0.9");
                            holder.relativeLayoutMission.setAlpha(alpha);
                            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(obj.picture, Base64.DEFAULT);
                            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                            Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(decodedByte.getWidth(), decodedByte.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                            BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(decodedByte, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
                            Paint paint = new Paint();
                            paint.setShader(shader);
                            Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
                            c.drawCircle(decodedByte.getWidth() / 2, decodedByte.getHeight() / 2, decodedByte.getWidth() / 2, paint);
                            holder.civilianImage.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);
                          }
                      }
                return convertView;
                  }
                 }
enter code here
11-02 20:36:11.344  30864-30864/net.httpiamheroic.herioc E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: net.httpiamheroic.herioc, PID: 30864
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at net.httpiamheroic.herioc.net.httpiamherioc.Activities.CityNewsFeedActivity$ListViewAdapter.getView(CityNewsFeedActivity.java:419)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2450)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1891)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:792)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:756)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5728)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4826)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:807)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:601)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:791)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: We need to know whether you used only one image or adapter in scroll view.
Also if Adapter, how is it implemented?

Comment: Its a listView which is set to an adapter and in the getView i am calling the above code @SuneelPrakash

Comment: @SuneelPrakash i updated my code can u look at it please. Thank you

Comment: Stacktrace please...

Comment: i updated it @TacB0sS

Comment: @TacB0sS 
Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(decodedByte.getWidth(), decodedByte.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Comment: Which means that decodedByte is null which means that the decodedString is not an image or not one that Android can create, which means that the content of obj.picture is not what you expect... try to add a print to the obj.picture length at 416...

Comment: Also see this answer for a more constructive pattern to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362854/listview-how-to-access-items-elements-programmatically-from-outside/26567212#26567212

Answer (score 0):

Change your getView method like this
Also check what if obj.accepted_rejected.equals("success") is false

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder=null;
        // Your row view 
        View rowView = convertView;

        if (rowView == null)
        {
            // New holder object 
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.civilianImage = rowView.findViewById(R.id.civilianimageview);// Your xml image view id

                            rowView.setTag(holder);

           } else{
                // Use existing holder object 
              holder=(ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
           }
        if (obj.accepted_rejected.equals("success")){
            holder.relativeLayoutMission.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mission_successful);
            Float alpha = Float.valueOf("0.9");
            holder.relativeLayoutMission.setAlpha(alpha);
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(obj.picture, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(decodedByte.getWidth(), decodedByte.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(decodedByte, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setShader(shader);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
            c.drawCircle(decodedByte.getWidth() / 2, decodedByte.getHeight() / 2, decodedByte.getWidth() / 2, paint);
            holder.civilianImage.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);
        }else{
            // Handle this case
        }
          return rowView;
     }
```

Comment: what is rowView? and yes i am handling the else of the if(obj.accepted_rejected.equals("success"))
but still the error is presented

Comment: Changed code you have to use bitmap creation every time not only when convertview is null. Please try and let me know.

Comment: the problem is when i scroll fast directly when the activity launch it crashes but when i do it gently it don't weird

Comment: You need to have a loader till minimum views are fetched that is first one. Bitmap processing normally takes time

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately(Stupidly) multiple methods that has to do with image handling in Android does not throw an exception when provided data that is not an image, they simply return null... WTH?

So as it seems the reason for the error is due to a wrong input to:

```
byte[] decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(...)
```

Which returns **null**, and forces the app to crash on the next line trying to use the *decodedByte*

```
Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(decodedByte.getWidth(), decodedByte.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```